# How to subset a dataframe from another dataframe with different length ?

Tags: r, vectorization

How to subset a dataframe from another dataframe of different length ? 
eg: I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, how do I subset `df1` using `df2`'s `Year, Month, Day, Hour` so it will become something like the `Expected Outcome`?

Where `Year, Month, Day, Hour` from row 4, 6, 7 in `df1` matches `df2`'s row 1, 2, 3 so only row 4, 6, 7 in `df1` is in the expected outcome.

**df1**

```
    V1  Year Month Day Hour Min Sec   Weight
1  1640 1999    02  05   04  00  00 1.936074
2  1519 1999    02  10   12  00  00 1.944277
3  1219 1999    02  25   16  00  00 1.947789
4  1720 1999    03  11   16  00  00 1.946841
5  1782 1999    03  18   08  00  00 1.956711
6  1523 1999    03  24   12  00  00 1.965768
7  1153 1999    04  01   16  00  00 1.981121
8  1262 1999    04  08   16  00  00 1.987066
9  1860 1999    04  15   00  00  00 1.982274
10 1624 1999    04  28   08  00  00 1.999045
```

**df2**

```
    V1  Year Month Day Hour Min Sec   Weight
1  3587 1999    03  11   16  00  00 2.836074
2  4675 1999    03  24   12  00  00 2.854277
3  3592 1999    04  01   16  00  00 2.917789
4  2980 1999    04  12   16  00  00 2.926841
5  2857 1999    04  18   16  00  00 2.986711
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
    V1  Year Month Day Hour Min Sec   Weight
4  1720 1999    03  11   16  00  00 1.946841
6  1523 1999    03  24   12  00  00 1.965768
7  1153 1999    04  01   16  00  00 1.981121
```

Comment: You can do it with `merge`, but then you need to filter the columns from `df2`, `merge(df1, df2, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `semi_join` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"))
```

This will return only the rows in `df1` that are matched in `df2` by the Year, Month, Day and Hour columns. Unlike some of the other joins, it is not mutating, meaning it won't add the columns of `df2` to the result.

Comment: Definitely more elegant than using `inner_join`. :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.